# Cannot create production database on DigitalOcean droplet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, digital-ocean

I tried to deploy my rails app into DigitalOcean following this page.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-ruby-on-rails-one-click-application-on-digitalocean#configuration-details

Everything work fine but i cant create the database via this command

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
```

Even i ran this command inside my app folder

```
chown -R rails: /home/rails/myapp_name
```

This is what i got from the command line

```
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "rails"
.
.
.
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"xxx", "username"=>"rails", "password"=>nil}
```

So how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: the user you are using for creating the database is rails, did you set up postgresql to have a superuser named rails?

Comment: `ALTER USER youruser WITH SUPERUSER;`

Comment: I can pass issue so do you know how can i create new custom ENV because i cannot migrate the database.

Answer (score 1):

The error shows that you are not providing a password of the `rails` Postgres user. The DigitalOcean Ruby on Rails "One-Click" displays the automatically generated password for the user in the MOTD (message of the day) that is displayed when you log into the server.

The password is also exported in the `APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD` environmental variable in `/etc/default/unicorn` In your `database.yml` file you can reference it using `<%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>`

Before running rake commands, source the file so that you can access the environmental variable:

```
. /etc/default/unicorn
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
```